# Bind to Moniker not working on Windows XP 32bit using LDAP

Tags: com

I have the following code:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="rootDN" value="LDAP://[The rest of the path]"/>
</appSettings>

string rootDN = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["rootDN"]; 
object ou = Marshal.BindToMoniker(rootDN);
```

This is producing an error:

> Unhandled Exception:
>   System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
>   (0x80072020): A n operations error
>   occurred. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80072020)    at
>   System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.MkParseDisplayName(IBindCtx
>   pbc, St ring szUserName, UInt32&
>   pchEaten, IMoniker& ppmk)    at
>   System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.BindToMoniker(String
>   monikerName)    at
>   LDAP_CreateGroup.Program.Main(String[]
>   args)

Works fine on Windows Server 2008, not working on XP. Unfortunately need this to run on XP.

Answer (score 0):

Must be logged on as domain user, run as user didn't work.